# react native converting array into string

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to print out array's value, converting into string in the description of  `mapview` marker. 
when I put `<Text>nameList</text>` inside of `return()` under `<View style={styles.container}>` is okay, but `description={nameList.toString()}` in  is just print out `{object,object}, {object,object}, {object,object}`

Please let me know how would I solve.

```
constructor(){
super()
this.state = {name: []}

}

  componentDidMount(){

   return fetch('https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/6090282/live.jsonapp_id=8425e834&app_key=a9de6fe50081ecf38d2e9c9d5f1a87e0&group=route&nextbuses=yes')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
for(var x in responseJson.departures){
this.setState({ 
state : this.state["name"].push(responseJson.departures[x][0])

});
}



   })
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
  }




render() {


const info = this.state.name;
const nameList = info.map(name =>{
  return(

    <Text key={name.line}>{name.line}{name.aimed_departure_time}</Text>
  ) 

})

 return (

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView
initialRegion={{
  latitude: 37.78825,
  longitude: -122.4324,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
}}
>

  <MapView.Marker
   coordinate={{
   latitude: 37.78825,
  longitude: -122.4324,
   }}
   title={'Hello'}
   description={nameList.toString()}

   />

    </MapView>

 </View>

 }
```

Comment: Do you want to have multiple markers with an invidual title/description?

Comment: no need   multiple markers, but just display something like  {{name.line},{name.aimed_departure_time}} , {{name.line},{name.aimed_departure_time}}

Comment: You made `nameList` a *Text Component* and it’s inner text content can’t be extracted using `.toString()`. Use a string instead, see Vipin’s edited answer below for a solution

Comment: You mean  const nameList should be var nameList = info.map (......?

Comment: @DHC You can return a **string** in the `nameList` map and then use `nameList.join(',')` to create a full string from the array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
JSON.stringify(nameList)
```

instead of

```
nameList.toString()
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

**Edited**

Change your map to

```
const nameList = info.map(name => {
  return `${name.line} : ${name.aimed_departure_time}`
})
```